# BuildFailedException: Failed to export self-signing certificate for appx Package

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono, hololens

I am building a small app for Hololens 2. When I choose "Build And Run" in Unity, it makes it close to the end, but I get this error:

```
BuildFailedException: Failed to export self-signing certificate for appx Package.
Output:System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate.
```

Here are my build settings:

[image: screenshot of unity settings]

Other settings:

- Unity 2019.4.14f1
- Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.2

What I have tried:

- generating a certificate with a password
- generating a certificate without a password
- executable only build type
- D3D Project build type
- restarting Unity
- installing the certificate on my machine
- restarting my computer
- Using "Build" instead of "Build And Run". This results in "Build succeeded".
- Switching to ARM architecture instead of ARM64
- Following deployment instructions at https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/BuildAndDeploy.html

What do I need to change to get this to deploy successfully?

Comment: Have you tried only building and then rather do the final build and deployment on Visual Studio? Also maybe try and delete any already added certificate

Comment: Thanks - it built successfully. I will look up how to deploy from Visual Studio - I've only done it from Unity.

Comment: Open the generated .sln file in VS, set it to Arm64 and hit project -> Store -> create app package. For me this was the most stable way.

Comment: Though now that I see it I think you had to provide the device portal address (e.g. 127.0.0.1:10080 via USB) and credentials below `Build configuration` .. have you tried that?

Comment: I've had lots of problems with VS. E.g. I see neither an ARM64 option, or the publish option you see. I've installed all kinds of ARM64 workloads in the installer though. Maybe Visual Studio Community can't do it?

Edit: Trying USB deployment

Comment: It still fails when deploying via USB in Unity: `Failed to sign appx Package`. I'll keep looking at Visual Studio though.

Comment: Sorry bro, I'm only on the phone right now. I'm only using the community version so this shouldn't be the issue. But I  know the struggle to get this build pipeline running correctly ..  sorry that I can't help further right now. Try again to follow this https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/BuildAndDeploy.html and maybe also this one https://circuitstream.com/blog/hololens-2-setup-guide/#holo5

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for your help - because of your suggestion, I realized the problem might be with Visual Studio specifically. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To fix:

1. Uninstall *all* Visual Studio stuff. Visual Studio, Build tools, everything.
2. Reinstall Visual studio following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools?tabs=unity
3. Install a few additional packages. Visual Studio Installer -> Modify -> Individual Components tab, find "C++ Universal Windows Platform support for v142 build tools (ARM 64)" and "C++ (v142) Universal Windows Platform tools", and select "Modify" in the bottom right.

After that I was able to deploy the package to the Hololens, using the D3D build type and a new build folder.